# How to use JQuery with the C# WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to perform this jquery action in my C# application : 
`$(".icon-radiobutton").click()`

I tried the following :

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName(".icon-radiobutton").InvokeMember("click")
```

But it seems like that's not the way to do it.

Comment: jQuery is client-side - you need to call that from one of your web pages, not in the .cs file (which is server-side).

Comment: But this works ? : 
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("description").SetAttribute("value", descTextbox.Text);

Comment: @ragerory This appears to be not an ASP.NET enviornment. Instead, it looks like the Windows Forms WebBrowser controls (embedded IE) and he's trying to manipulate on the client side.

Comment: Indeed i've made an instance of my webbrowser inside the application

Comment: I'm not familiar with `GetElementByName`, but it implies that it's going to find elements by the element name itself rather than by class.  You're trying to search by class.

Comment: `GetElementByName` is not the same as `$()` as in jQuery. Your code and what you want to achieve are way apart. [Wrap your javascript code in a script.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @mason ah right. Should probably add an extra tag on this question it was a little misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a javascript function to do it and call that using your webBrowser component

js:

```
function MyCLickFunction()
{
    $(".icon-radiobutton").click()
}
```

c#:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("MyCLickFunction");
```

Comment: How would you get it to see that JavaScript function? Do you insert it into the document? Do you register it somehow?

Comment: You've got it, sorry I wasn't clear. The JS would need to be in the target page of the web browser control

Comment: And what if the JS isn't in the target page, and it's a page you don't control (a common scenario)?

Comment: If you don't control the page, I'm not sure why you would need to be manipulating it. Theoretically you could call eval with your javascript, but it's hacky and insecure, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I'm trying to make an application that goes to a page with a form. After that he has to fill in the form.

Comment: @NeilP The WebBrowser control is commonly used (rightly or wrongly) to programatically manipulate 3rd party websites.