# Finding selectors within a string, and editing the string based on X selectors

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm currently successfully adding static image adverts onto my site using `jQuery`.

This is an example snippet of code on how I'm doing this.

```
$('#reviewCont > p:nth-child(3)').append("The Image HTML");
```

I'm now trying to use specific scripts to deliver native ads to my platform, and I'd like to use C# to find `p:nth-child(3)`, `p:nth-child(6)` etc, within a string, and insert the scripts & HTML needed, server-side.

I have a bit of experience using HTMLAgilityPack, which would deal with this effortlessly while scraping, but as I'm getting the content (the string) from my database, it seems a bit of an overkill using HTMLAgility, without even scraping any content?

Surely there's a way of finding these selectors, and editing the string without third-party extensions - just how I already do with `jQuery` - or have I answered my own question, and using HTMLAgilityPack is probably recommended?

Comment: If the Html for the page is in a database and the page has jQuery you could use WebBrowser class provided in .Net Framework and [run jQuery in your web browser object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159035/how-to-use-jquery-with-the-c-sharp-webbrowser-control). Otherwise, you could use HtmlAgilityPack, convert sizzle syntax of the selectors into xpath and [append the content](https://html-agility-pack.net/append-child). Agility Pack should execute faster, because it's not running a browser in background.